# Webpack build throws a error

Tags: angular, webpack

I have just updated my webpack configruation to the new version from the angular2-webpack-starterkit but now my build throw the following strange error in a node module. 
I use this;:
node v4.4.7
npm v3.10.5
Window 10 64bit

```
    mypath\node_modules\webpack\lib\LibManifestPlugin.js:46
                        var content = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(manifest, null, 2), "utf8");
                        ^
TypeError: utf8 is not a function
    at Function.from (native)
    at Function.from (native)
    at LibManifestPlugin.<anonymous> (mypath\node_modules\webpack\lib\LibManifestPlugin.js:46:25)
    at mypath\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3025:16
    at eachOfArrayLike (mypath\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:941:9)
    at eachOf (mypath\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:991:5)
    at Object.eachLimit (mypath\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3089:3)
    at LibManifestPlugin.<anonymous> (mypath\node_modules\webpack\lib\LibManifestPlugin.js:14:9)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (mypath\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:142:13)
    at Compiler.emitAssets (mypath\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:292:7)
    at onCompiled (mypath\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:231:11)
    at mypath\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:477:13
    at next (mypath\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:138:11)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (mypath\node_modules\webpack\lib\CachePlugin.js:62:5)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (mypath\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:142:13)
    at mypath\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:474:10
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (mypath\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:131:46)
    at mypath\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:615:19
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (mypath\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:131:46)
    at mypath\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:606:11
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (mypath\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:131:46)
    at mypath\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:601:10
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (mypath\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:131:46)
    at sealPart2 (mypath\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:597:9)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (mypath\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:131:46)
    at Compilation.seal (mypath\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:545:8)
    at mypath\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:471:16
    at mypath\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:225:11
    at mypath\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:452:11
    at mypath\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:423:13
```

Here my package.config:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build:aot:prod": "npm run clean:dist && npm run clean:aot && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:aot": "npm run build:aot:prod",
    "build:dev": "npm run clean:dist && webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
    "build:prod": "npm run clean:dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "ci:aot": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
    "ci:jit": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e",
    "ci:nobuild": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
    "ci:testall": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
    "ci:travis": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:dev && npm run e2e:travis && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e:travis && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e:travis",
    "ci": "npm run ci:testall",
    "clean:dll": "npm run rimraf -- dll",
    "clean:aot": "npm run rimraf -- compiled",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist compiled dll",
    "docker": "docker",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "e2e:live": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:live",
    "e2e:travis": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:delay",
    "e2e": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor",
    "github-deploy:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubDev",
    "github-deploy:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubProd",
    "github-deploy": "npm run github-deploy:dev",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "postinstall": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "protractor:delay": "sleep 3 && npm run protractor",
    "protractor:live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist -c-1 --cors",
    "server:prod:ci": "http-server dist -p 3000 -c-1 --cors",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "test": "npm run lint && karma start",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.4.3",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~2.4.3",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.34",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "~2.53.39",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "^2.0.0",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "~3.0.0-beta.17",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "find-root": "^1.0.0",
    "gh-pages": "^0.12.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.21.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "1.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.1",
    "ng-router-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "ngc-webpack": "1.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.2.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.0",
    "parse5": "^3.0.1",
    "protractor": "^4.0.14",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.3.1",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.3",
    "typescript": "~2.1.4",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "v8-lazy-parse-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack": "2.2.0-rc.4",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.2.0-rc.0",
    "webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "~2.3.1"
  }
}
```

**#UPDATE#**
Just tried now to clone the starterkit and to run the npm run build:dev task with the same error. Maybe ths is a bug

Comment: seems to be some dependency missing delete the folder **node_modules** and then run **npm install**

Comment: hmm I have done a fresh git clone of https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter and npm install and the nom run build:dev and I recive that error

Comment: try this **`npm remove webpack -g`** and then this
**`npm i webpack --save-dev`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by changing the node version to 6.9.4 https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/1372